# How to make clock_gettime using CLOCK_REALTIME monotonic?

Tags: c++, linux, time

A problem with CLOCK_REALTIME is that it isn't monotonic and that time can potentially go backwards if a NTP sync occurred.

Would it be safe to do something like the following to make it monotonic?

```
struct timespec GetMonotonicTime()
{
    static struct timespec last = timespec();
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
    last.tv_nsec = (last.tv_sec == ts.tv_sec) ? std::max(last.tv_nsec, ts.tv_nsec) : ts.tv_nsec;
    last.tv_sec = std::max(last.tv_sec, ts.tv_sec);

    return last;
}
```

Comment: You can use [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to having problems if ever run in a multi-threaded envinronment your `ns` attribute will asymptote to 999999999 as time passes.

Linux provides `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` if that happens to be your platform (and it would satisfy your needs).

Comment: I could perhaps make it thread-safe if I made the last variable thread-local using the gcc __thread keyword. You are indeed correct about the ns attribute.

Comment: @Nathan Doromal even your corrected code won't do what you want if the `sec` portion moves back in time simultaneous to a `ns` change.